# Firmware update using MSPDEBUG goes directly into the debugging console

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, msp

I have encountered a strange problem using mspdebug with my MSP430FR5969 launchpad.
I have recently started with msp430 programming. I was interested in running the [Curve25519](https://munacl.cryptojedi.org/curve25519-msp430.shtml) project on MSP430. I followed there instruction step by step to install gcc-msp430, mspdebug etc with other dependencies. Since I could not find the slac460k.zip file in TI website I downloaded the latest slac460w.zip file. 
Now whenever I type

> mspdebug --allow-fw-update tilib

It directly goes inside the mspdebug (screenshots attached).
[image: afte mspdebug]
I think it is supposed to update the firmware with this command.
I can see the red LED glowing after I execute the above command.
[image]

Moreover, I can't run any program on the microcontroller. I tried with a small blinkng program from the mspdebug prompt by executing the command

> prog a.out

But I can't see the LED blinking. And the program runs forever.
I will appreciate if you can tell what am I doing wrong here.
I appreciate your help.

Edit :
[image: Prog a.out and run]

I used usb connector to connect my device to my laptop.

Edit : 
Code for Blinky.

```
            #include <msp430fr5969.h>

            int main(void) {
              volatile int i,j;

              // stop watchdog timer
              WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;
              // set up bit 0 of P1 as output
              P1DIR = 0x01;
              // intialize bit 0 of P1 to 0
              P1OUT = 0x00;

              P1OUT ^= 0x01;
              // loop forever
              for (j=0;j<=1000;j++) {
                // toggle bit 0 of P1
                P1OUT ^= 0x01;
                // delay for a while
                for (i = 0; i < 0x6000; i++);
              }

            return 0;
            }
```

Comment: What does `prog` output? Did you exit `mspdebug` afterwards, or `run`?

Comment: @CL. I typed run. But nothing happens. Then I exit. I can see the red LED going off after I exit.

Comment: Does the same method work to run a plain blinky program?

Comment: @CL. I am not entirely sure what you meant. However, I added the code for a blinky program.

Comment: That program does not work because it does not clear LOCKLPM5.